# How do I reconnect to a custom GCP VM with Google COLAB?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-colaboratory, reconnect

I followed this [guide](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html), created a VM, and connected with a Colab notebook.
The notebook ran for a few days and everything was fine until I got disconnected.
How do I reconnect to the same VM?

The guide states:

> Connecting to a custom GCE VM puts you in control of your machine lifecycle. You will still experience disconnections from your VM from interruptions to your connection, but Colab will not alter the VM state: your work and progress will be saved and available when you reconnect.

but I can't reconnect to it.

I tried reconnecting using the same notebook, a new empty notebook, and finally I restarted the VM and got always the same response:

> The requested VM does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the issue. It was working fine and suddenly disconnected. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I gave up

Comment: I found the solution. I'll post it here @Alessandro

Answer (score -1):

I found out that Google colab is not designed for long term experiments (as even written in the above quote). Instead, you have to create a Deep Learning instance and then connect it to the Colab. I am using it actually through remote VScode ssh connect. The connection is stable since a few weeks, with no cuts.

Here are the instructions:
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/cloud-marketplace